# libgdx build constantly fails cause of LWJGL

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx, lwjgl

I just wanted to begin with libgdx development. I followed the instructions with the setup tool and created my first project. I wanted to try to build it but then I got an error and found out that it has something to do with lwjgl and I found online that it should be changed to lwjgl3. But now I still get an error and the build fails:

```
[LWJGL] Failed to load a library. Possible solutions:
    a) Add the directory that contains the shared library to -Djava.library.path or -Dorg.lwjgl.librarypath.
    b) Add the JAR that contains the shared library to the classpath.
[LWJGL] Enable debug mode with -Dorg.lwjgl.util.Debug=true for better diagnostics.
[LWJGL] Enable the SharedLibraryLoader debug mode with -Dorg.lwjgl.util.DebugLoader=true for better diagnostics.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Failed to locate library: liblwjgl.dylib
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:162)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:62)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.<clinit>(Library.java:50)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.<clinit>(MemoryUtil.java:97)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Pointer$Default.<clinit>(Pointer.java:67)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Callback.<clinit>(Callback.java:41)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3Application.initializeGlfw(Lwjgl3Application.java:81)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3Application.<init>(Lwjgl3Application.java:91)
    at com.bernhardp.tucker.desktop.DesktopLauncher.main(DesktopLauncher.java:10)
```

Does anyone know what causes this problem? I also tried to download the LWJGl jars and add them to the library.
I am using IntelliJ CE as IDEA.

Best wishes.

Comment: Can you share what command are you using to build?

Comment: I recommend you use this tool to create your project instead of the official setup tool. It defaults to Lwjgl3 and is a smoother start-up experience for new libgdx users. The development team is considering replacing the official setup tool with this one. https://github.com/tommyettinger/gdx-liftoff